# Performing http GET and POST request in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby on rails.I want to perform HTTP GET and HTTP POST request. For HTTP GET, I have coded and it is working fine, **but for HTTP POST I am not able to figure it out**.

Following is the code snippet for http GET :

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("http://www.adobe.com")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
response = http.request(request)
puts response.body
```

Comment: Isn't the doc clear enough?

Comment: @Sergio: May i know which doc you are referring to ?

Comment: for POST operation my code should take 2 inputs i.e. target url and xml request body.

Comment: This one, of course: [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html).

Comment: Any modification in existing http GET request code, will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

I have use the Following one which you can use both get and post.

```
def invoke_webservice url
query_string = url[:query_string].blank? ? "" : url[:query_string].map{ |key, value|
                 "#{key}=#{CGI.escape(value)}" }.join("&").insert(0, "?")
url[:class] = url[:class].blank? ? "" : url[:class]
webservice_uri = URI.join(APP_CONFIG['webservice_uri_format'], '/application/',
                   url[:class], url[:action], query_string)
uri = URI.parse(webservice_uri.to_s)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
#http.use_ssl = true
#http.verify_mode =  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
http.open_timeout = 25
http.read_timeout = 500
http.start do |http|
  if url[:method] == 'get'
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
  else
    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new uri.path, initheader = { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }
    request.body = url[:data].to_json
  end
  request.basic_auth APP_CONFIG['username'], APP_CONFIG['password']
  response = http.request request
  JSON.parse(response.body) if response.code =~ /^2\d\d$/
end
  rescue => e
puts "Error Message is #{e.inspect} #{e.backtrace}"
  end  
end
```